# Does Lokijs generates its own IDs?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit, lokijs

I've been trying to use [lokijs](http://lokijs.org/) on a project.

Does Lokijs generates its own IDs? Or do we need to handle that our selves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LokiJS generates its own ids. Since the property "id" is a common name, to avoid clashes the unique id of an object inserted in  a collection is stored in the property `$loki`. The other loki-generated data is the `meta` object containing information about the object creation and last update, as well as the revision number (number of times an object was modified).